# NSlookup seems to work fine but ping cannot reach my nameserver

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I have this nslookup check from network-tools.com

http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=ns3.alrconsultores.com&type=255&server=74.3.161.94&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000&go.x=26&go.y=15

And it seems to be everything oK

I configure my godaddy domain pointing ns3.alrconsultores.com to my ip aamof they respond me this:

I'm not the most knowledgeable when it comes to setting up custom DNS settings and overall GoDaddy.com's support team is pretty limited in the support they can provide with custom DNS issues.  I'm not too sure what the issue could be, but hopefully some other community users will be able to provide some input and get you pointed in the right direction.  I did, however, check to confirm that the nameserver of NS3.ALRCONSULTORES.COM is fully registered and pointing to the IP address of 74.3.161.94.

So.. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong I have opened the dns port for incoming connections and it seems to be working fine.. the icmp echo is allowed just for ping tests over the ip. I just can´t ping ns3.alrconsultores.com

What possibly can be happening?

Comment: Yes thanks... it was a misinformation actually the DNS was configured perfectly find but I was disoriented regarding the glue records, so I change the nameservers for the entire domain and it works... 

**Thank you very much everyone :D**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the name server (NS3.ALRCONSULTORES.COM) has an entry for itself configured correctly.  That means doing an NSLOOKUP and asking that particular server for the IP address of itself works.

However, when I try and do an NSLOOKUP using my ISP DNS servers it fails which would indicate that the records have not been propogated to a "real" external DNS server

Comment: When did you update the MX records?  Propogation depends on the TTL of those entries, so you might want to check those settings as well...

Comment: Agreed. You need glue records on .com for your new nameserver, and your other nameservers should also have NS and A records for the new server.

Comment: So I have this host summary on Godaddy :
NS1 pointing to my old server -> 216.18.xx.xx
NS2 pointing to my old server -> 216.18.xx.xx
NS3 pointing to this actual ip
NS4 pointing to this actual ip

Comment: So the entire domain have the nameservers ns1 and ns2... you mean I have to put the nameservers to ns3 and ns4 for the entire domain if I want this domain to act as a nameserver?